# Отправка писем

Tags: email, php

Из php.ini:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
;sendmail_path =

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =
```

Менять нельзя. Обычный `mail()` при отправке возвращает тру. Значит письмо отправлено, однако ничего не приходит. Как быть?

P.S. Ни в какой спам там ничего не попадает. Письмо просто не приходит.

Comment: и отправляется наверное с локального сервера все это...

Comment: Как информативно. Если имеет значение с какого сервера отправляется вот ссыль http://hosting.tomsknet.ru/